# Logging from a .Net app to Kiwi Syslog, how to set Priority?

Tags: c#, log4net, syslog

I am trying to send a syslog message to a kiwi syslog server utilizing log4net on my WebAPI. I've installed an evaluation version of kiwi syslog locally, it has the default values (reads UDP, port 514) and my following configuration works for log4net, well kind of:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
      <param name="RemoteAddress" value="127.0.0.1" />
      <param name="RemotePort" value="514" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="ALL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="UdpAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

But when I get the messages in Kiwi Syslog Server I see
[image: imageNot]

Which corresponds to this piece of code:

```
        Log.Info(log.ToString());
        Log.Debug(log.ToString());
        Log.Warn(log.ToString());
        Log.Error(log.ToString());
```

Where `private static readonly ILog Log = 
LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);`

Is there any way to let the log4net logger map the priority (info, debug, warn, error) to the priorities in kiwi syslogs?

Comment: Never used it, but there is a special Syslog4net appender that might do a better job. See https://github.com/Cayan-LLC/syslog4net

Comment: And there's a built-in [RemoteSyslogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender.html)